# How to create S3 bucket using AWS Lambda python?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto

I am creating a AWS Lambda function using Python. I want to create S3 bucket but I am getting error as the bucket name provided by me is not JSON serializable.

Here is the code I used for creating a bucket with Lambda:

```
import boto from boto 
import s3 from boto.s3.connection 
import S3Connection

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  conn = S3Connection('access_key','secret_access_key')
  print "Connection:",conn
  bucket = conn.create_bucket('bucketname')
  print bucket
  return bucket
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are using and the error message you are experiencing. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please find below code  which I used for creating bucket with Lambda:-
import boto
from boto import s3
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    conn = S3Connection('access_key','secret_access_key')
    print "Connection:",conn
    bucket = conn.create_bucket('bucketname')
    print bucket
    return bucket

Comment: Feel free to Edit your question rather than adding code in a comment. Within a Lambda function, there is no need to obtain an Access Key and Secret Key. It is automatically provided as a result of assigning a Role to the Lambda function. Did you Lambda function work? What error did you receive? You can view the log in Amazon CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: Please show the exception error.

Answer (score 3):

From [Creating and Using Amazon S3 Buckets](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html) boto3 documentation:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.create_bucket(Bucket='my-bucket')
```

Rules for bucket names:

- The bucket name can be **between 3 and 63 characters long**, and can contain only lower-case characters, numbers, periods, and dashes.
- Each label in the bucket name must start with a lowercase letter or number.
- The bucket name cannot contain underscores, end with a dash, have consecutive periods, or use dashes adjacent to periods.
- The bucket name cannot be formatted as an IP address (198.51.100.24).

Comment: I followed all the rules for S3 bucket.

Comment: this worked for me

 s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    b = s3.Bucket('laddu47')
    b.create(CreateBucketConfiguration={ 'LocationConstraint': 'ap-south-1' })